# Smartest way to join two SQL tables on a lookup value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have two tables in Sql Server 2008

```
Items
------
ItemNo
StartDate


Translation
-------
ItemNo
StartDate
Language
Description
```

In the Translations table there are multiple translations for each product, ie.

```
ItemNo: 123
StartDate: 2011-11-02
Language: SE
Description: 'Bla1'
ItemNo: 123
StartDate: 2011-11-02
Language: DK
Description: 'Bla2'
```

How can I build a fast select statement that outputs a single line for each product without using too many lookups, like

```
    Itemno  StartDate  DK     SE
------------------------------------
    123     2011-11-02 Bla1   Bla2
```

Thanx in advance
Jens

Comment: What you actually need is converting rows to columns, and you can find more than a few answers here on SO. hope it helps :)

Comment: Search for [SQL Server]+PIVOT : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+[SQL+Server]+PIVOT

Comment: There are various way to do this (using `CASE`, using `LEFT JOIN`s, using `PIVOT`).

Comment: Thanx ypercube. Your link was very useful. I could transform rows into colums and do a regular innerjoin. 

I did some testing, and it turned out that the transform method was much slower than doing a regular lookup. So I'm sticking with this as a solution

    SELECT Items.StartingDate,
           'DK' = (
      select T.Description from Translation T where T.[ItemNo] = Items.ItemNo 
      and S.StartingDate = T.StartingDate
      and T.Language = 'DK' ),
          ...same for other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version using XML to do what you want. I have not tested the performance against the other methods suggested in the comment sections.

Can't see why `StartDate` should be in both tables other than that it is part of the PK in `Items` table. If `StartDate` is not part of the PK you can safely remove it from all joins.

```
declare @Items table
(
  ItemNo int,
  StartDate date
)

declare @Translation table
(
  ItemNo int,
  StartDate date,
  Language varchar(2),
  Description varchar(20)
)

insert into @Items values
(123, '2011-11-02')

insert into @Translation values
(123, '2011-11-02', 'DK', 'Bla1'),
(123, '2011-11-02', 'SE', 'Bla2')


select I.ItemNo,
       I.StartDate,
       T.Trans.value('(Trans[@Language="DK"]/Desc)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as DK,
       T.Trans.value('(Trans[@Language="SE"]/Desc)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as SE
from @Items as I
  inner join (select T1.ItemNo,
                     T1.StartDate,
                     (select T2.Language as '@Language',
                             T2.Description as 'Desc'
                      from @Translation as T2
                      where T1.ItemNo = T2.ItemNo and
                            T1.StartDate = T2.StartDate
                      for xml path('Trans'), type) as Trans
              from @Translation as T1
              group by T1.ItemNo,
                       T1.StartDate) as T
    on I.ItemNo = T.ItemNo and
       I.StartDate = T.StartDate
```